# Why doesn't stubgen generate types for literal collections?

Tags: python, mypy, stub

For example, on this file:

```py
MY_DICT = {'a': 0, 'b': 1, 'c': 2}
MY_LIST = ['a', 'b', 'c']
MY_TUPLE = ('a', 'b', 'c')
```

It generates:

```py
from _typeshed import Incomplete

MY_DICT: Incomplete
MY_LIST: Incomplete
MY_TUPLE: Incomplete
```

I would have expected:

```py
MY_DICT: dict[str, int]
MY_LIST: list[str]
MY_TUPLE: tuple[str]
```

Why can't it infer it? Or does it operate on the premise that the values can change and we can only really know what the *intended* type is from a handwritten annotation?

Comment: Wow... Just noticed that even when initializing variables like `my_instance = MyClass()`, you need to provide explicit type annotations like `my_instance: MyClass = MyClass()`. It feels a bit redundant. Otherwise, you get `Incomplete` type hints.

Comment: It looks like this is the intended behavior for `stubgen`, the types are never inferred. I can't find any documentation giving any details on that though, so please link it if you can find anything.

Comment: [The auto-generated stub files often require some manual updates, and most types will default to Any.](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/stubgen.html)